# Nextjs pm2 Error ERR_TLS_CERT_ALTNAME_INVALID

Tags: nginx, next.js, ssl-certificate

How can fix this error in nextjs??
Proect deployed via pm2 and nginx

Error [ERR_TLS_CERT_ALTNAME_INVALID]: Hostname/IP does not match certificate's altnames: Host: scimagine.com. is not in the cert's altnames: DNS:auth.scimagine.com

Quickly solving problem)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

The TLS/SSL certificate which you are using for your application isn't issued for the hostname (`scimagine.com`) through which you are trying to access it. The certificate only contains the hostname `auth.scimagine.com`. Either get a new certificate with the correct hostname that you are using with your application, or update the existing one to add your hostname as well.